# How do I define methods in a Mongoose model?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, coffeescript, mongoose

My `locationsModel` file:

```
mongoose = require 'mongoose'
threeTaps = require '../modules/threeTaps'

Schema = mongoose.Schema
ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId

LocationSchema =
  latitude: String
  longitude: String
  locationText: String

Location = new Schema LocationSchema

Location.methods.testFunc = (callback) ->
  console.log 'in test'


mongoose.model('Location', Location);
```

To call it, I'm using:

```
myLocation.testFunc {locationText: locationText}, (err, results) ->
```

But I get an error:

```
TypeError: Object function model() {
    Model.apply(this, arguments);
  } has no method 'testFunc'
```

Answer (score 51):

You didn't specify whether you were looking to define class or instance methods. Since others have covered instance methods, [here's](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#statics) how you'd define a class/static method:

```
animalSchema.statics.findByName = function (name, cb) {
    return this.find({ 
        name: new RegExp(name, 'i') 
    }, cb);
}
```

Comment: Just to complete your answer this is usage example (from same page):
`var Animal = mongoose.model('Animal', animalSchema);`
Animal.findByName('fido', function (err, animals) {console.log(animals)});

Comment: Hooray for static! That what I was looking for

Comment: this.find is not defined. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 33):

Hmm - I think your code should be looking more like this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

var threeTaps = require '../modules/threeTaps';


var LocationSchema = new Schema ({
   latitude: String,
   longitude: String,
   locationText: String
});


LocationSchema.methods.testFunc = function testFunc(params, callback) {
  //implementation code goes here
}

mongoose.model('Location', LocationSchema);
module.exports = mongoose.model('Location');
```

Then your calling code can require the above module and instantiate the model like this:

```
 var Location = require('model file');
 var aLocation = new Location();
```

and access your method like this:

```
  aLocation.testFunc(params, function() { //handle callback here });
```

Comment: Sorry if I'm misreading here, but I don't see how this differs from the OPs code.

Comment: Can the same method be used somehow using mongoDB shell?

Comment: @Will, I think the difference is that iZ. is applying the function to the Schema not the Model.

Answer (score 20):

See the [Mongoose docs on methods](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#methods)

```
var animalSchema = new Schema({ name: String, type: String });

animalSchema.methods.findSimilarTypes = function (cb) {
  return this.model('Animal').find({ type: this.type }, cb);
}
```

Comment: The problem is, in my execution, I get "animal.findSimilarTypes is not a function" message!

Comment: In my case, with the exact same example`this.model` is undefined. Any idea why?

Comment: Answering myself, the issue was because I used an arrow function for one of the Schema methods, which was using the scope of the schema and not the instance model itself.

Answer (score 1):

```
Location.methods.testFunc = (callback) ->
  console.log 'in test'
```

should be

```
LocationSchema.methods.testFunc = (callback) ->
  console.log 'in test'
```

The methods have to be a part of the schema. Not the model.