# Node.js find() in Mongoose model definition

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I want to define a method on my model that involves searching the documents of the same model, here is what I tried:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Author = require('./author.js'); 

var bookSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    author : { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'author' },
    genre: String,
});

bookSchema.methods.findSimilar = function(callback) {
    bookSchema.find({'genre': this.genre}).exec(function doThings(err, doc){ 
        /* ... */ 
    }); 
}; 
module.exports = mongoose.model('book', bookSchema, 'book');
```

However, I get `TypeError: bookSchema.find is not a function`.

I also tried `bookSchema.methods.find()`, same result. How can I fix this?

Thanks,

**Edit:**
Inspired by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12117733/2483127), I also tried `this.model('Book').find()`, but I get a similar error: `TypeError: this.model is not a function`

Comment: I believe u need to first define a model to use the function `find()`. 

[API DOCs reference](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose#accessing-a-model)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your method to:
(I assume you have already exported model **Book** from your schema module.

```
bookSchema.methods.findSimilar = function(callback) {

    this.model('Book').find({'genre': this.genre}).exec(function doThings(err, doc){ 
        /* ... */ 

    }); 

    // Or if Book model is exported in the same module
    // this will work too:
    // Book.find({'genre': this.genre}).exec(function doThings(err, doc){ 
    //     /* ... */ 
    //    
    // }); 
};
```

The method will be available on the instance of your model:

```
var book = new Book({ author: author_id, genre: 'some_genre' });
// Or you could use a book document retrieved from database

book.findSimilarTypes(function(err, books) {
    console.log(books);
});
```

See [documentation here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#methods).

**EDIT** *(Complete Schema/Model Code)*

The complete schema/model code will be as follows:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Author = require('./author.js'); 

var BookSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    author : { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Author' },
    genre: String,
});

BookSchema.methods.findSimilar = function(callback) {
    Book.find({genre: this.genre}).exec(function doThings(err, doc){ 
        /* ... */ 
    }); 
}; 

const Book = module.exports = mongoose.model('Book', BookSchema);
```

Usage example:

```
var book = new Book({ author: author_id, genre: 'some_genre' });
// Or you could use a book document retrieved from database

book.findSimilarTypes(function(err, books) {
    console.log(books);
});
```

Comment: Did you create a model for this schema? If you exported a model for this schema from the same module (named `Book`), you can use `Book.find({'genre': this.genre}).exec(function doThings(err, doc) { // ... // })`

Comment: I thought this file was the model :) In other files, I include this like `var Book = require('./models/thisfile');` and then do `Book.find(..)`. I can define my methods on external files (like controllers) but I just wonder if I can make it part of the model. **Edit:** I forgot the last line where I do `module.exports = ...`. But it's confusing. Should I define the function before I export the model, or after? Neither seems logical right now :D

Comment: I got confused with PascalCasing & CamelCasing in your code. Usually we use PascalCasing for schema & models and camelCasing for instances. See my edit above. I have included complete code for how your schema/model module should be. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is still confusing me, the `Book` inside `findSimilar` is defined after the function definition. How does it work? And what does the `const` do? Again, thanks a lot.

Comment: Even though `Book` is defined after the function definition, the module is loaded before you call the function and so `Book` gets already defined. `const` is constant (ES6). You could use `var` if you prefer.

Comment: OK, thanks. This works. However, I have another problem. I cannot do `doc.save` inside `findSimilarTypes` because `doc.save` is not a function. Anyways, this will be another question :)

Comment: When you are inside the method, you have to do *this.save()*. If you are inside the callback function then,  before calling *findSimilarTypes*, you must do a *var doc = this;*, and inside the callback you can *doc.save()*. Hope this helps.

Comment: You can also do **book.save()** where book is the instance of the document.

Comment: Sorry I meant to do `doc.save` inside `doThings`, i.e. I want to update the document found by it (I'm sure it will find only one)

Comment: Are you getting a valid **doc** and there is no error?

Comment: Yes, I print it and everything looks fine.

Comment: Ah ok... You are doing **Book.find()** and that will return array of doc. So you must call **doc[0].save()**. You have another option of using **Book.findOne()** which returns single doc and in that case you can call **doc.save()**

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to write new keyword, so do this :

```
var bookSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    author : { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'author' },
    genre: String,
});
```

Cheers:)

Comment: Strange, I defined all my models without `new`, and everything works. I wonder if there is a difference. **P.S.** adding it didn't solve the issue.